# ActionBar MenuItem selector

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

Is it possible to change the Image of a MenuItem when pressed and can that be done by a selector (different MenuItems should be changed with a different image when pressed or selected).

Some sample code would be nice.

I looked up a lot of solutions but not many of them made a clear explanation. Cheers !

Comment: People can help you more easily if you also provide some information on what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> Is it possible to change the Image of a MenuItem when pressed and can
>   that be done by a selector

Yep, absolutely. Here's an example:

Add a selector to your `drawable` folder.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Pressed state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_your_pressed_icon" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!-- Default state -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_action_your_default_icon"/>

</selector>
```

Apply the selector to your `MenuItem` using the `icon` attribute:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item android:icon="@drawable/your_menu_item_selector" ... />

</menu>
```

Comment: This is not working for me.