# How to change Background color of menuItem in android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I am working on programmatically add a menu-Item into menu. I want to add background color on selection to particular Item. How can I add background to menuItem?

[image]

Your answer would be appreciated.

Comment: This answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659637/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-action-bars-option-menu-in-android-4-2

Comment: please check http://stackoverflow.com/a/28979152/3790150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly You need to create an Style for popmenu  as you want refer below sample for that

```
<style name="MyApp.PopupMenu" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:textStyle">@style/commonEditTextTheme</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/pop_up_menu_bg_with_shadow</item>
</style>
```

Place of drawable you can also replace with color as you needed or make XML Drawable into your drawable folder

```
<style name="commonEditTextTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
</style>
```

this pop menu theme add in your main application or activity theme like below

```
<!--My Theme-->
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    ......
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyApp.PopupMenu</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3):

While other answers provide change style (which will affect **all** menu items, and, as I understand, need is to change one menu item),
I propose you to use `android:actionLayout` attribute to implement your custom layour for menu item.

See [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html) for it (search actionLayout there, it's very simple actually).

Also I think there is a possibility to make a [`selector`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14023886/android-button-selector) as your layout and use it.

**Update.** Sorry, I mislead you :(
All of this will work only if MenuItem is shown as Action (not when pressing on three dots).
Seems like guys given other answers were right - the only way to customize this is changing themes.
But please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652368/using-a-selector-for-a-menuitem-in-the-actionbar) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23795871/actionbar-menuitem-selector) - it might help you to provide selector for your purpose.
Also you can create [PopupMenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21329132/android-custom-dropdown-popup-menu) or even [PopupWindow](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html), last one is fully customizable.
The last option is to create custom Spinner, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31760081/dropdown-menu-items-with-custom-views-android-showasaction-never).

Hope something from this will help you. Thanks.

Comment: you are right,can you explain how to add actionlayout into menuItem  programmatically android